# Please help with this limit of a sequence: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \bigg(n\sqrt[3]{1+\frac1n} - n\sqrt[3]{1+\frac1{n^2}}\bigg)$

Tags: limits

I have this limit of a sequence: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg(n\sqrt[3]{1+\frac1n} - n\sqrt[3]{1+\frac1{n^2}}\bigg).$$
Can I modify this expression to this expression by knowing that fractions goes to $0$?: $\lim n-n$. How to modify this solution to get the limit?

Comment: What is $n$ approaching in this limit?

Comment: It is approaching to infinity.

Comment: And $n$ are natural numbers greater than zero.

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Use $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$

Comment: And is my modification to $lim (n-n)$ right?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Can I simplify the limit in the title to this form?: $lim(n-n)$

Comment: No, clearly from answers below you see that the $\lim$ is not equal to $0$. Or perhaps I still don't understand what you mean by $\lim(n-n) $ form.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a=\sqrt[3]{n^3+n^2},\,b=\sqrt[3]{n^3+n}$ so $a-b=\frac{a^3-b^3}{a^2+ab+b^2}=\frac{n^2-n}{a^2+ab+b^2}\approx\frac{n^2}{n^2+n^2+n^2}=\frac13$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

By binomial approximation

$$\sqrt[3]{1+\frac1n}=1+\frac1{3n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)$$

$$\sqrt[3]{1+\frac1{n^2}}=1+\frac1{3n^2}+o\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$

these can be obtained by

$$f(x)=\sqrt[3]{1+x} \implies f'(x)=\frac13\frac1{(1+x)^\frac23}\implies f'(0)=\frac13$$

and therefore as $h\to 0$

$$f(h)=f(0)+f'(0)\cdot h+o(h)=1+\frac h3+o(h) $$

Comment: You can make this approach exact by writing $1+1/(3n)+o(1/n)$ and $1+o(1/n)$ respectively.

Comment: Sorry but I think I do not know what is binomial approximation. In school we did not do that..

Comment: @PeterForeman Yes of course! It was just a hint, but I'll add that.

Answer (score 0):

If $x = (1+1/n)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ and $y = (1+1/n^{2})^{\frac{1}{3}}$, we can multiply and divide the argument by $x^{2}+xy+y^{2}$ to use $x^{3}-y^{3}  =(x-y)(x^{2}+xy+y^{2})$.

Note that $$n\bigg{[}\bigg{(}1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg{)}^{\frac{1}{3}}-\bigg{(}1+\frac{1}{n^{2}}\bigg{)}^{\frac{1}{3}}\bigg{]}\frac{\bigg{[}\bigg{(}1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg{)}^{\frac{2}{3}}+\bigg{(}1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg{)}^{\frac{1}{3}}\bigg{(}1+\frac{1}{n^{2}}\bigg{)}^{\frac{1}{3}}+\bigg{(}1+\frac{1}{n^{2}}\bigg{)}^{\frac{2}{3}}\bigg{]}}{\bigg{[}\bigg{(}1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg{)}^{\frac{2}{3}}+\bigg{(}1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg{)}^{\frac{1}{3}}\bigg{(}1+\frac{1}{n^{2}}\bigg{)}^{\frac{1}{3}}+\bigg{(}1+\frac{1}{n^{2}}\bigg{)}^{\frac{2}{3}}\bigg{]}} \\ =\frac{n\bigg{[}\bigg{(}1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg{)}-\bigg{(}1+\frac{1}{n^{2}}\bigg{)}\bigg{]}}{\bigg{(}1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg{)}^{\frac{2}{3}}+\bigg{(}1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg{)}^{\frac{1}{3}}\bigg{(}1+\frac{1}{n^{2}}\bigg{)}^{\frac{1}{3}}+\bigg{(}1+\frac{1}{n^{2}}\bigg{)}^{\frac{2}{3}}} \\ = \frac{1-\frac{1}{n}}{\bigg{(}1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg{)}^{\frac{2}{3}}+\bigg{(}1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg{)}^{\frac{1}{3}}\bigg{(}1+\frac{1}{n^{2}}\bigg{)}^{\frac{1}{3}}+\bigg{(}1+\frac{1}{n^{2}}\bigg{)}^{\frac{2}{3}}}$$

Now, when $n \to \infty$ the denominator goes to 3 and the numerator goes to 1, so your limit is 1/3.

Answer (score 0):

MVT :

Let $x>y$:  Then $f(x)-(y)=f'(s)(x-y)$, $y<s<x$;

$f(x)=x^{1/3}$.

$n((1+1/n)^{1/3}-(1+1/n^2)^{1/3})=$

$n(1/3)(1+t)^{-2/3}(1/n-1/n^2)$, where $1+1/n^2 <t<1+1/n$;

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} t=0$.

$(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(1/3)(1+t)^{-2/3})\cdot $

$(\lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty}(n(1/n-1/n^2))=$

$(1/3) \cdot 1$.